# Message assign operator not using swap

Tags: c++, c++11

sorry if the title was a little off, didn't know what to use.

So in this book(C++ Primer 5th ed) I'm learning C++ from I got an question:

> We did not use copy and swap to define the Message assignment
>   operator. Why do you suppose this is so?

I really have no idea as both result in the same thing even when assigning the same object t itself.

***main.cpp for both files:***

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Folder.hpp"
#include "Message.hpp"

int main()
{
    Message m("Hello");
    Folder f1, f3;

    m.save(f1);

    Message m2;

    m2 = m;

    m2.save(f3);
    m2.save(f1);

    std::cout << f3.msgs.size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << f1.msgs.size() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

***swap function:***

```
void swap(Message &lhs, Message &rhs)
{
    using std::swap;

    for (auto f : lhs.folders)
        f->remMsg(&lhs);
    for (auto f : rhs.folders)
        f->remMsg(&rhs);

    swap(lhs.folders, rhs.folders);
    swap(lhs.contents, rhs.contents);

    for (auto f : lhs.folders)
        f->addMsg(&lhs);
    for (auto f : rhs.folders)
        f->addMsg(&rhs);
}
```

***Without using swap***

***operator=:***

```
Message& Message::operator=(const Message &rhs)
{
    remove_from_Folders();
    contents = rhs.contents;
    folders = rhs.folders;
    add_to_Folders(rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

***Changes by using swap:***

**Message.hpp**
    Message& operator=(Message);    // new declaration to match def

**Message.cpp**

```
Message& Message::operator=(Message rhs)
{
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}
```

Output is

```
2
1
```

as expected for both versions.

I really have no idea what the upside of not using swap would be other then a little less work to be done.

***Classes:***

```
// Message.hpp

#ifndef MESSAGE_HPP
#define MESSAGE_HPP

#include <string>
#include <set>

class Folder;

class Message
{
        friend class Folder;
        friend void swap(Message&, Message&);
        friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const Message &m);
public:
        explicit Message(const std::string &str = "") : contents(str) { }

        ~Message();

        Message(const Message&);
        Message& operator=(const Message&);

        void save(Folder&);
        void remove(Folder&);
private:
        std::string contents;
        std::set<Folder*> folders;

        void add_to_Folders(const Message&);
        void remove_from_Folders();
};

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &, const Message &);

#endif






// Message.cpp

#include "Message.hpp"
#include "Folder.hpp"

void swap(Message &lhs, Message &rhs)
{
        using std::swap;

        for (auto f : lhs.folders)
                f->remMsg(&lhs);
        for (auto f : rhs.folders)
                f->remMsg(&rhs);

        swap(lhs.folders, rhs.folders);
        swap(lhs.contents, rhs.contents);

        for (auto f : lhs.folders)
                f->addMsg(&lhs);
        for (auto f : rhs.folders)
                f->addMsg(&rhs);
}

void Message::save(Folder &f)
{
        folders.insert(&f);
        f.addMsg(this);
}

void Message::remove(Folder &f)
{
        folders.erase(&f);
        f.remMsg(this);
}


void Message::add_to_Folders(const Message &m)
{
        for (auto f : m.folders)
                f->addMsg(this);
}

void Message::remove_from_Folders()
{
        for (auto f : folders)
                f->remMsg(this);
        folders.clear();
}


Message::~Message()
{
        remove_from_Folders();
}

Message::Message(const Message &m) : contents(m.contents), folders(m.folders)
{
        add_to_Folders(m);
}

Message& Message::operator=(const Message &rhs)
{
        remove_from_Folders();
        contents = rhs.contents;
        folders = rhs.folders;
        add_to_Folders(rhs);
        return *this;
}


std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, const Message &m)
{
        os << m.contents;
        return os;
}




// Folder.hpp

#ifndef FOLDER_HPP
#define FOLDER_HPP

#include <ostream>
#include <set>

class Message;

class Folder
{
        friend class Message;
        friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream &, Folder &);
public:
        ~Folder();

        void addMsg(Message *);
        void remMsg(Message *);
private:
        std::set<Message*> msgs;
};

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &, Folder &);

#endif




// Folder.cpp

#include "Folder.hpp"
#include "Message.hpp"

Folder::~Folder()
{
        for (auto &m : msgs)
        {
                m->remove(*this);
        }
}

void Folder::addMsg(Message *m)
{
        msgs.insert(m);
}

void Folder::remMsg(Message *m)
{
        msgs.erase(m);
}

std::ostream& print(std::ostream &os, Folder &f)
{
        for (const auto &m : f.msgs)
        {
                print(os, *m) << std::endl;
        }

        return os;
}
```

Cheers

Comment: Probably `remove_from_Folders()` etc make nothrow guarantees?

Comment: Please post the relevant code here. Personally I won't click pastebin links, but it's really more so that StackOverflow can be self-contained in case of link decay AND because we're too lazy to click the link.

Comment: You may like to try removing references to `Message` from `Folder`, that would obviate the need to do the re-pointing in `swap`.

Comment: Does the book go on to answer its own question..?

Comment: @AndyG So swap does not make a nothrow guarantee? I've posted the code onto here so you can check it out now.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin What do you mean, Folder has pointers to Message.

Comment: @MattMcNabb I wish it did, would solve so much of my half-sure answers.

Comment: Answer may be found here. https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer/tree/master/ch13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @KeithSmith posted a link to the answers and I got two from there. Here they are:

> ### Exercise 13.38:
>
> > We did not use copy and swap to define the Message assignment operator. Why do you suppose this is so?
>
> @Mooophy The copy and swap is an elegant way when working with
>   dynamically allocated memory. In the Message class ,nothing is allocated
>   dynamically. Thus using this idiom makes no sense and will make it
>   more complicated to implement due to the pointers that point back.
>
> @pezy In this case, `swap` function is special. It will be clear two
>   `Message`'s folders , then swap members, and added themselves to each
>   folders. But, `Message` assignment operator just clear itself, and
>   copy the members, and added itself to each folders. The `rhs` don't
>   need to clear and add to folders. So, if using copy and swap to
>   define, it will be very inefficiency.

Basically Mooophy is saying that copy and swap is something used for dynamically allocated memory and the Message class has not dynamically allocated memory.

pezy is saying that swap is different that it swap adds both lhs and rhs to each folder and the assignment operator just adds lhs which is more efficient.

Just wanted to say thanks to KeithSmith for letting me know of the link.

Link: https://github.com/Mooophy/Cpp-Primer